# What is the quartic undecidable Diophantine equation with 58 unknowns that's undecidable?

Tags: diophantine-equations, decidability

I found in Jones' 1980 work "Undecidable Diophantine Equations" Theorem 4 that it is claimed that at least one 58 unknown quartic Diophantine equation is known to be undecidable. It is not explicitly listed what the coefficients/form of this equation is in this paper; is there some place/reference where it is explicitly listed?

Comment: It is not explicitly listed, but you can follow the construction which is given there:"Then, by transposing terms to one side and
summing squares one can construct a universal Diophantine equation in $58$ unknowns
and degree $4$."

Comment: Hi! It's the sentence before that that I find less constructive; the bit about "by adding 30 variables you can reduce the degree to 2. Is this bit obvious?

Comment: We cannot have an explicite example of such a polynomial since we then would KNOW that there is no solution contradicting that it is an undecidable instance.

Comment: What is however possible that we have a polynomial from which we know that there is no solution which can be proven in ZFC, but not in PA.

Comment: Hi Peter, I don't think that's correct, because theorem 3 for example gives an explicit high degree undecidable Diophantine, and it remains undecidable. This is all I want, but for degree 4 and with 58 unknowns.

Comment: @NingBao And how can they KNOW that there is no solution if no formal system can show this ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean a polynomial with a parameter and we cannot decide for which values of this parameter, there is a solution. This can actually be done.

Comment: @Peter, the OP's description of the polynomial is correct, even if it's counterintuitive. I think you'll be interested in looking into [Hilbert's tenth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_tenth_problem).

Comment: @GregMartin That such a polynomial exists does not mean we can construct it.

Comment: All the information is out there for you. You just have to be willing to see it through your preconceptions.

Comment: Still not sure how to do the nonconstructive step in Jones paper (regarding reduction to degree 2); if anyone has any ideas, I would be glad to hear it